# Sum of a function involving $n-$root

Tags: functions, power-series

I'm trying to find the series of
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^{3}}$$
Can I just use the fact that
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum x^{n},\quad|x|<1$$
writting $x^{3}$ in the place of $x$ and then, getting this:
$$\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum x^{n} & \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x^{3}}=\sum x^{3n} \\
                           & \Rightarrow \left(\frac{1}{1-x^{3}}\right)^{-1/2}=\left(\sum x^{3n}\right)^{-1/2} \\
                           & \Rightarrow \sqrt{1-x^{3}}=\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{3n}}}
\end{align*}$$

I don't know, it looks wrong to me. I know I can multiply or divide by anything different from $n$, but is it right?

Thanks :)

Comment: No. $3=1+1+1$, but $\sqrt{3} \neq \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1}$.

Comment: The square root function is not linear

Comment: I knew it was wrong haha so what can I do?

Comment: Try starting with the series for $\sqrt{1+x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $z:=-x^3$, and try to use [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for $\sqrt{1+z}$ then write back $z=-x^3$.